# Needs to search file a file in Linux

Tags: linux

I need to search class file in server. I dont know which folder the class is present. 
whether we can achieve through find command.

I tried with below command.

```
find /apps -type f | xargs grep BackendClient.class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -name "BackendClient.class"
```

This helps you finding that file everywhere on your system.

Be aware however: if it's embedded in a jar-file, you won't find it.
In that case, you might do the following:

```
find ./ -name "*.jar" -exec jar tvf {} \; | grep "BackendClient.class"
```

Comment: There may be a chance of that file will be in jar. In this case, is there any way to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the filename:

```bash
find /apps/ -type f -name "BackendClient.class"
```

If you are not sure if the name exact as you think you can use the case-insensitive version:

```bash
find /apps/ -type f -iname "BackendClient.class"
```